# Ember Object in path STRING could not be found or was destroyed

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I have a small application where I'm getting translations json for a locale and updating Ember.STRINGS. Am I doing something wrong?

```
$.get("http://localhost:8000/translations.json", {locale : locale}, function (data) {
    Ember.set('STRINGS', data) ;
});
```

In 0.9.5 I was doing

> ```
> Ember.STRINGS = data
> ```

;
and it seemed to work. When I changed it to 1.0.0 a lot of things started crashing around. Both of these don't work.

> ```
> Ember.STRINGS = data ;
> Ember.set('STRINGS', data) ;
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an exemple of how I get this to work in v1.0.0-rc.1 :

```
$.getJSON('mysql.php', { action: 'translate', lang_id: 2 }, function(data){
    var translation = {};
    $.each(data, function() {
        translation[this[0]] = this[1];
    })
    Ember.STRINGS = translation;
})
```

Hope this helps...